# How to token an empty string after a word

Tags: java, token

I want to type "sin(35)" into a textfield, but to calculate it, I have to separate every operator and number with a space since I used .split(" "), how do I set the delimiter to be the empty string after a number or operator, so it can accept no spaces?

```
pseudocode: infix.split("" after sin | "" after [()+-*^])
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you maybe clarify with an example?

Comment: I don't see a space at the end. Are you sure you couldn't just ignore it with `.trim()` ?

Comment: You mean you want to split with `""` not a white space? If yes, that wouldn't possible. You need to use substring , indexOf , ... methods

Answer (score 2):

If you are simply trying to use split to get the formula parameter, you could use the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes instead, like so:

```
String function = "";
int parameter = 0;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(sin)\\((\\d+)\\)"); // Compile the regex pattern.
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("sin(35)");           // Instantiate a pattern Matcher to search the string.
while (matcher.find()) {                                // For every match...
    function = matcher.group(1);                        // Get group `$1`.
    String s = matcher.group(2);                        // Get group `$2`.
    parameter = Integer.parseInt(s);                    // Parse to int, throws `NumberFormatException` if $2 is not a number.
}
System.out.println(function);                           // Prints "sin".
System.out.println(parameter);                          // Prints 35.
```

Regex:

```
(sin)\((\d+)\)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: How did you create this image? :)

Answer (score 1):

You only need one line to extract each part:

```
String function = input.replaceAll("\\(.*", "");
String parameter = input.replaceAll(".*\\(|\\).*", "");
```

Comment: +1 I hadn't considered simply removing the unnecessary parts of the String.